# Resolving Email Addresses during Outlook send() method

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in, exchange-server

I am developing an Outlook 2010 Addin using C# and VSTO. This Addin is supposed to encrypt the message body and attachments before it sends. I built a Ribbon which has "send secured" label and I put the work in the click event for button on the Ribbon.

The problem is that I have to validate user input in the "TO" ,"CC",and "BCC" bars. I am having problem that in Outlook forms, the recipients in some cases shows contact name or e-mail address. Therefore, validating the form of e-mail address is not enough I have to validate if contact name exists in exchange and retrieve his address (resolve). This resolution is necessary since I have to modify message and resend it according to the recipients e-mail.

Is it possible to call the form validation method of send() function to verify user entries? If not, do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Are you just wanting the email addresses of the recipients?